# Integration of $x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{1-\alpha}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm trying to solve a definite integral $$\int^{1}_{0} x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{1-\alpha}dx $$ where $-1<\Re\alpha<2$ with a beta function: $$B(2-\alpha, \alpha + 1) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(2-\alpha)}{\Gamma(3)}$$ Is there a way to solve Gamma functions in the numerator for complex $\alpha$? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for a simplification or for a verification of your given formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator can be further simplified assuming this is what you meant by *solve Gamma functions in the numerator for complex $\alpha$*. According to the functional relation of the Gamma Function combined with [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) we get

$$\begin{align}
B(2-\alpha,\alpha+1)&=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(2-\alpha)}{\Gamma(3)}\\
&=\frac12\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)(1-\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)\\
&=\frac{\alpha(1-\alpha)}2\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)
\end{align}$$

> $$\therefore~B(2-\alpha,\alpha+1)=\frac{\alpha(1-\alpha)}2\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi \alpha)}$$

Note that this is only valid as long as $\alpha\notin\mathbb Z$ hence for $\alpha\in\mathbb Z$ the denominator equals $0$.

---

In case you are interested in a proof of the fundamental relation between the Beta and the Gamma Function I would recommend you to take a look at *J.G.*'s answer.

Comment: I thought the Euler's Reflection Formula can't be used for complex values. Is it possible for the Residue Theorem to be applicable?

Comment: @AmirGorgonzolaNurlanov Why do you think it cannot be used for complex values? The Beta Function is defined for all $x,y$ such that $\Re x,y >0$ and therefore also for complex arguments. The shortest proof I am aware of can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Reflection_Formula) and does not restrict the values to be real but only not to be integer. Could you rephrase your question hence I am not sure whether I understand what exactly you mean by *"Is it possible for the Residue Theorem to be applicable?"*

Comment: I was thinking of the case when $\alpha$ is an integer and we get a singularity. Is there a way to solve it for these cases? Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @AmirGorgonzolaNurlanov Uff. To be honest I am not quite sure. The only possible integer within your given interval would be $\alpha=1$ for which the original integral is elemetary solvable. In more general I think the residue theory is a good starting point for such integrals but my knowledge concerning complex analysis is still quite weak. The singularity in Euler's Reflection Formula occurs also on the LHS for all integer $>0$ since then the $\Gamma(1-z)$ term becomes $\Gamma(-n)$ which is a simple pole of the Gamma Function for all integer $n$.